# Selected text font detection

Tags: fonts, selection, font-family

The problem is next:

1. I have an empty `textarea`.
2. Then I paste some outside text inside it with specific `font`.
3. I select (highlight) some part of this text.
4. I need to detect, what is the `font` of the `selection`.

Note, that textarea's text is plain, there is no `HTML` formatting inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textarea will only render in the font the page specifies, so you could get the font using jQuery by doing something like:

```
var font = $("textarea").css("font-family");
```

However it sounds like you want to know the font that the text was in originally. Unfortunately that isn't possible as the font information is lost when pasting into the browser.

Comment: Yes, I want to know the original font. Is it really impossible?

Comment: @Halfist: Yes, it's impossible.